# How to make user enter only positive numeric value for factorial

Tags: php

I want users to enter only positive number to calculate factorial not alphabets and not negative numbers in form of html in php as i am new to php  , how can i?

```
<div id="mydiv">
<?php if(isset($_POST['fa'])) 
{ $val = $_POST['factori']; $valu=$val-1; while ( $valu!=1 ) 
{ $val=$valu*$val; $valu--; } } 
?> 
<form method="post" action=""> <h2>Calculate factorial for any number<br></h2>
```

Comment: Where is your try? Do search on net and get some pre-populated code and try it.If you can't done anything with the code, please post it here.

Comment: i am not able to upload picture of my code some reputation required :(


so here is the code

Comment: <div id="mydiv">
   
    <?php
     if(isset($_POST['fa']))
     {
     
       
       $val = $_POST['factori'];
       $valu=$val-1;
      while ( $valu!=1 ) {
       
       $val=$valu*$val;
       $valu--;

      }
      
     
      
      
     }
     ?> 
    <form method="post" action="">
    <h2>Calculate factorial for any number<br></h2>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to forbid people to enter negative numbers in your client (front-end) then you must use JavaScript to listen to changes in the input area and you must validate them using regex (or simply by checking if the input value is negative or not), you can give certain warning messages and make the submit form become invalid.

Another approach is just to allow the user to post any numeric value to your back-end (PHP) and there you can simply check if the value is legit, if it's not legit you can simply return the error instead of of the calculated value.

Make an attempt to solve the problem and come back to us if you hit a wall.

Comment: <div id="mydiv">
   
    <?php
     if(isset($_POST['fa']))
     {
     
       
       $val = $_POST['factori'];
       $valu=$val-1;
      while ( $valu!=1 ) {
       
       $val=$valu*$val;
       $valu--;

      }
      
     
      
      
     }
     ?> 
    <form method="post" action="">
    <h2>Calculate factorial for any number<br></h2>

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way, check if number is numeric and > 0

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['fa'])) 
    { 
            $val = $_POST['factori']; 
            if(is_numeric($val) && $val > 0) // check if input is numeric and  > 0
            { //valid input
              $valu=$val-1; 
              while ( $valu!=1 ) 
              { 
                    $val=$valu*$val; $valu--; 
              } 
            }
            else
            {
                   // input is not numeric or is < 0
            } 

    } 
    ?> 
    <form method="post" action=""> <h2>Calculate factorial for any number<br></h2>
```